# How to crate a Visual Interface to an Openedge Program

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I´m an Intern Developer and new to Openedge language and I´m doing some exercises that the company that I work for gave me to study the language. This is the exercise:

> Develop a simple calculator that can do the 4 basic math operations.
>   The program must contain:
>
> - One .p file for the interface
> - One .p file for the calculator logic
> - One menu for choosing the wanted operation
>
> Use the *update* command to get the values in the screen and the
>   *display* command to show the options.

I studied C++ and I know how to create an interface that wait for the user input and operate upon it. The problem is that in Openedge, until now, I only developed programs that ran one time with hard coded variables, how I will do this kind of thing in Openedge? Create a visual menu that waits for the user to type some input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you say you should use `UPDATE` and `DISPLAY` I'm guessing you should develop a text based user interface.

A very simple menu could be like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cCmd AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

DO WHILE cCmd <> "X" :

    DISPLAY 
        "1) command one" SKIP
        "2) command two" SKIP
        "3) command three" SKIP
        "X) Leave menu" WITH FRAME frameMenu 4 DOWN WIDTH 20.

    UPDATE cCmd LABEL "Choice".

    CASE cCmd:
        WHEN "1" THEN MESSAGE "Command one".
        WHEN "2" THEN MESSAGE "Command two".
        WHEN "3" THEN MESSAGE "Command three".          
        OTHERWISE MESSAGE "Unknown command".
    END CASE.    

END.
```

Comment: I didn't imagine it was that easy, thanks for the help!